# loading dataframe into table postgres and pandas with auto-incrementing id

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql

Is it possible to use the `to_sql` method in load a pandas dataframe into postgres if I have an incrementing column?  Whenever I try to load the dataframe in my postgres table, the incrementing column `id` disappears.  My dataframe I'm using to load into postgres does not contain the id, its just `name, role and location`.

my table:

```
CREATE TABLE Mytable (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    role VARCHAR(50),
    location VARCHAR(50),
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_by_name ON mytable (name);
```

inserting the table:

```
engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost/cool_database")
df = pd.read_excel(mycooldataframe.xlsx)

df.to_sql("mytable", engine, if_exists="replace", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `if_exists="append"` in your `to_sql` function.
If you use `"replace"` instead it might recreate the table using only the columns in the excel file.